# PurgeIdleCellConnections causes application to freeze then crash

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

My app keeps rapidly throwing this up at me until we run out of memory and hang:

```
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1ddde360
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1dddb9a0
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1e87d4b0
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x21b98a60
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x21baeae0
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1dde92c0
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x21b3a3a0
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x21ce0a40
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1e81b4d0
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x21987880
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x21994d50
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x21b463b0
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1e81b2b0
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1dde2130
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1dd02cc0
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x21987130
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1e89b610
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x21a7c5a0
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x219307e0
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x21b44240
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x21b6f290
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x219c1db0
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1e81c5f0
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x21957890
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x21cd86f0
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x21cd6660
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x21b43140
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x21cd4400
```

Any idea what this is? I'm fairly new to iOS but I couldn't find anything on this.

Hopefully somebody has seen this before.

Comment: Same problem here. Where is this coming from? I'm getting this: purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1e2c64a0, so same thing. Any ideas anybody?

Comment: i seem to see debug statements like this using the new xcode dev preview, that could be why this is happening, unfortunately that is under nda now and discussions should be on the apple dev forums

Comment: This is happening for me on xcode 4.5, so it's not just a beta iOS6 issue. I found that this happened to me when i had problems with my proxy configuration, so I wasn't able to access the internet.

Answer (score 2):

There's an ongoing discussion in the Apple Developer Forums about this: https://devforums.apple.com/message/687713#687713

Comment: This isn't under NDA anymore... anyone have an idea what this means? It doesn't crash my app, but I'm not sure if it's an issue or perhaps a bug in the iOS 6.0 SDK? The link isn't very useful...

Comment: As far as I know this was Apple debugging code that made it into one of the betas. I haven't seen it since that beta.

Comment: It's showing up in a released version of Xcode for me (v. 4.5). It looks like Xcode 4.5.1 was recently released, so I'll try downloading and using this new version (I believe at least that it's different based on the posted date). If it was only meant for Apple debugging, perhaps they've taken it out? We'll see... :) Thanks for the response.

Comment: I'm debugging right now with Xcode 4.5.1 and iOS 6 and I can confirm that is message continue to appear, any way it seems to me to be related to iOS instead of Xcode itself

Comment: I have this as well on Xcode 4.5.2

Comment: Despite the message, is it effecting anyone of your apps? is it effecting memory footprints? Have you submitted an app/update and have had it rejected for this reason?

Comment: Same here. The message is shown on console. In my experience, seems that this message is closely related to network problems of my application. When the message comes out the network is not working anymore. I need to shut down the application and restart it. Next week I will try with the last beta3 of iOS 6.1. Anyone out there with the same issues?