# UITextField emptied in UITableView when scrolled out of view

Tags: ios, forms, uitextfield

I have a UITableView with 6 UITextFields that are tagged in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method (0 through 5). I also attach a datePicker view to the inputView for fields 5 and 6 in the textFieldShouldBeginEditing: method based on the tags (4 and 5).

When data is entered into field 2, and then field 6 (date field) is tapped for input, the datePicker view slides up and field 2 is obstructed. When the input has been completed (or if you scroll up to bring field 2 into view, I can see that its contents are erased/emptied/deleted.

I am baffled by why this happens. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the cell has been deallocated to save memory. To combat this you need to store the contents of the text field in a variable. Then when the cell is recreated load the saved contents. If you need more details let me know...

Comment: I am not sure when it gets recreated (does `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` get called again). When and where should I save the value to a variable?

Comment: yes cellForRowAtIndexPath: does get called. When you recreate the textfield set it's text to your stored value. The way I stored the text was to use the textfield's delegate properties and watch for changes and store the new text to my variable.

Comment: I added some code to store the textfield to an instance variable in the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` and/or `textFieldShouldReturn:` methods but it now generates an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error with `purgeIdleCellConnections` identified. I did some research and found that this is a bug in iOS/XCode per: [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/687713#687713) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209725/purgeidlecellconnections-causes-application-to-freeze-then-crash)

Answer (score 0):

It is removing the textfield when it scrolls off the visible area of the tableview and recreating it(erasing the contents) when it comes back. You'll need to store the values of the text fields and set its values to the text fields when your table view recreates them.